# Register action at future intervals

Tags: android, sms

I'm experimenting with Android and would like to make an app that sends predefined texts to certain people at future intervals. Basically, initiating conversations with relatives every month or so, so they think I like them.

How do you register an activity or app to fire in the future?  I'd like to be able to change up the greeting, so that the relatives don't catch on.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use AlarmManager to trigger your app in the future. Here's a tutorial on how to use it: [Scheduling Repeating Alarms](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)